# Dividing all values of a dictionary by a value

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have the following code in C# where vector is a  [string,double] type of Dictionary.I want to divide all values in this dictionary by a value, "magnitude". Now, my naive first code was the following:

```
foreach (var key in vector.Keys)
{
    vector[key] = vector[key] / magnitude;
}
```

Which throws an exception, saying the Collection has been modified in a foreach. I may create a second dictionary to write the resulting values into, but I do not want this way.

Is there any easier way to do that, for example by using methods which operate on all Dictionary values, like the following?

```
vector.Values().Aggreagate(), vector.Values().Average()
```

Comment: Do you want to modify the dictionary at all? I'm asking because you haven't mentioned that. If you just want to calculate a value according to the dictionary values use a local variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *simplest* way to do this is just to copy the list of keys before iterating:

```
foreach (var key in vector.Keys.ToList())
{
    vector[key] = vector[key] / magnitude;
}
```

Or:

```
foreach (var entry in vector.ToList())
{
    vector[entry.Key] = entry.Value / magnitude;
}
```

(That avoids a double lookup, but will copy more data of course.)

It's a bit of a shame that modifying the value of an existing entry is seen as a change that prevents you from continuing to iterate over the keys, admittedly.

An alternative would be to have a mutable wrapper type as the value, then you could use:

```
foreach (var wrapper in vector.Values)
{        
    wrapper.Value = wrapper.Value / 10;
}
```

That wouldn't be modifying the *dictionary* at all - just the objects that the dictionary refers to. I personally wouldn't do this in most cases, but it *may* be appropriate for you.

Comment: The second solution you say "but will copy more data of course". Why - both the first and second create a shallow list of references of the same length right?

Comment: @weston: No, the first will just copy the keys. The second will copy the complete `KeyValuePair<,>` (which is a struct) in each case.

Comment: Ah didn't realise was a struct.

Answer (score 4):

This is ofcourse because you are modifying the dictionary while iterating. You can try iterating over copy of `Keys` instead of the actual collection

```
foreach (var key in vector.Keys.ToList())
{
    vector[key] = vector[key] / magnitude;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could avoid changing the collection by copying it as follows.

```
var CopiedKeys = vector.Keys.ToList();
foreach (var key in CopiedKeys)
{
    vector[key] = vector[key] / magnitude;
}
```

Comment: Didn't you change it yourself?

Comment: No, first a copy of all keys is made. The copy of the collection of keys has the same values as these of the vector, but they are different objects.

Comment: Ah,ok,I understand. I thought why we need to copy keys if we don't even change them. Now I understand that we are really changing keys.

Answer (score 2):

```
        dictionary = dictionary.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value / magnitude);
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative could be to used an incremental iterator

```
int magnitude = 2;
for (int index = 0; index < vector.Count; index++)
{
     String key = vector.ElementAt(index).Key;
     vector[key] = vector[key] / magnitude;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the most simple ways is to use ordinary for iteration like this sample:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < vector.Keys.Count; i++)
        {
            string key = vector.Keys.ElementAt(i);
            vector[key] /= magnitude;
        }
```

if you want to use Linq methods you can use this code:

```
vector=vector
            .Select(x=> new KeyValuePair<string,double>(x.Key,x.Value/magnitude))
            .ToDictionary( x=>x.Key,x=>x.Value);
```

Comment: Similar to Matt Gordon's response, but excellent use of /= operator.